# What is an elegant way to return the index of a list in python without looping?

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list `t = list(i for i in np.arange(0.5,10.5,0.5))`. I want to find the index positions of `s=[3,5,7]`within `t`. I understand I can do this via `t.index(s)` loop, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: does the list comprise of unique values?

Comment: Hey, yes it comprise of unique values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to realize that you always need some loops. Even [`t.index`](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) does a loop, it just hides it from you! However there is as far as I know no function in the Python standard library that avoids the explicit loop over `s` .

---

However one could make it more efficient (I mean more efficient than `[t.index(needle) for needle in s]`)! Especially if your list is sorted.

You already used `NumPy` so [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) would definitely be fast:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.5,10.5,0.5)
s = [3, 5, 7]

np.searchsorted(t, s)
```

If you want to stay in Python there is also the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) module, that at least saves some of the (implicit) looping:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def index(a, x):  # Taken from the bisect documentation
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect_left(a, x)
    if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
        return i
    raise ValueError

indices = [index(t, needle) for needle in s]
```

Comment: And if you really wanted to get fancy (and by fancy I mean engage in premature optimisation) you could sort the needle list too, and then pass the previously found index, incremented by 1, as the `lo` parameter to `bisect_left`.

Comment: @DavidScarlett That depends on how the values are distributed because `bisect` starts with the middle index (between `lo` and `hi`) first but the chances are quite good that the next value is close to the last found index (if it's very close it requires a lot of bisection steps). So you might have more steps until you find the next value. At least I found that it seldom performs better, most of the time it's slower.